# Not Able To Add To Array In "C"

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, printf, scanf

I have a program meant to calculate prime numbers of a specific number then I have to put it into an array in order to do some math to those numbers; however, I'm running into an issue where I am not able to put the prime numbers collected into an array.

**Current Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pairs.h"
#define SIZE 1000

int main(){
    int n, m, count, i=0, res = 0;
    char prime[SIZE];

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);


    // while(count >= 1){
    //     // count = getchar();
    //     // prime[i++] = count;
    for(count = n; count >= 2; count--){
        if(primed(count) == 0){
            prime[i++] = count;
        }

    }
    printf("%s",prime);
    return 0;

}

int primed(int num){
    int primes;
    for(primes = 2; primes<=num/2; primes++){
        if (num % primes != 0){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*I am hoping to add the numbers collected in the for-loop to an array*

Comment: "*not able to put the prime numbers collected into an array*". What does that mean exactly? And what is `primed` as that is not shown in the code. But for starters this isn't correct: `printf("%s",prime);`. `prime` is not a string and cannot be printed with `%s`.

Comment: `count = getchar();` Why are you calling `getchar`? Do you know what that does? Same with `putchar`.

Comment: The getchar() is used in the above to get the characters from count, the putchar() was actually mistakingly entered I edited the code, sorry.

Comment: And how about the `%s`? That's clearly wrong. You should not be operating on strings or even chars. Keep the array as `int` elements and write a function that loops over the array printing each int value seperately.

Comment: hey @kaylum I'm pretty new to the "C" language, now I get it if you're having a bad day but there's a polite way to talk to people. I am having an issue getting the digits into the array I have a plan once they get into the array to iterate over the array and check for possible pairs where the difference is equal to ```int m```. If you have any specific pointers to help then please list them. just trying to learn "C" like most.

Comment: I apologise if it comes off as impolite. But the comments have limited space. I was not trying to be rude but just getting straight to the point to highlight the remaining errors and things to fix. My point is  `%s` is for an ascii string. But your array is not a string. So if you are using that to check your results it may not come out right. So you need to fix that first.

Comment: @kaylum I converted the array into ```type int``` however I'm still running into an issue adding the numbers into the array as now it's printing some extra long number even when I'm only asking it to print ```prime[1]``` of the array. This whole thing was a lot easier in python...

Comment: But did you change the `%s` to `%d`? If I make that change it works for me. See [HERE](https://ideone.com/WpwDoY).

Comment: @kaylum I did however if I were to do it in a while loop I'm not able to access just the individual characters so I cant loop through them and do math because say for example when I just want to access ```prime[1]``` the output is ```5555``` when it should be ```3```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Using a loop is no different to accessing each element individually. It just accesses each of them in turn. The code in the link I gave you does access `prime[1]` in the loop and the value is correctly shown as `3`. Did you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code works, the problem is that you are not printing the array well, try this code for printing the array which has to the same type of the elements you want to put in, so `int prime[SIZE]`:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%d ", prime[j]);
printf("\n");
```

Note that the numbers will be in reverse order as you are starting the calculation from the last element, so if you input 10 you will have:

```
7 5 3 2
```

The %s you are using in order to print the array is used to print strings (char arrays terminated with the character '\0'). If you want to print every other type of array you must use a cycle and print every element.